# Getting file error in windows using git bash

Tags: bash, git, github, ssh, gitlab-ci

I am using git bash in windows to store the ssh key in ssh agent and run into this error.

```
$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
/c/Users/abhis/.ssh/id_rsa: No such file or directory
```

Then I removed .ssh/id_rsa and saved it with the name of the key file. It worked.

```
$ ssh-add ~/[myfilename]
Identity added: [My Folder name] (email id)
```

Why does this worked.

Comment: What do you mean by this: *Then I removed .ssh/id_rsa and saved it with the name of the key file. * Can you rephrase this to make your intention clear?

Answer (score 1):

`ssh-add` asks for the filename of the key. The error means that the program could not find a file called `~/.ssh/id_rsa`.

When you provided `ssh-add` with the actual filename of the keyfile, it worked, as expected.

For `ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa` to work, you should place the keyfile in your `~/.ssh` folder and name it `id_rsa`.